# MEX not finding VC++ compiler

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to use a VC++ compiler for MEX. It is installed on the PC, but not being picked up when I run "mex -setup -v". Below is the relevant output (I am on a Windows 10 PC). Any ideas?

```
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER19' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gcc.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gcc.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2019a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
```

Comment: Note: Visual Studio does **not** install the C++ compiler by default. This is the most common problem

Comment: Which version of MSVC do you have installed? It is looking explicitly for the 2015 version, if you have a different version it will not match. Each version of MATLAB is compatible with a different subset of MSVC versions.

Comment: I have installed: "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)" and "MSVC v141 - VS 2017 x64/x86 C++ build tools (v14.16)"